# Cant deploy on devices with debugging Xamarin Android and iOS

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using the latest Visual Studio (15.6.3) and can't deploy on device with debugging anymore. If I run without debugging it deploys. 
How can i fix it? Really annoying

iOS:

[image]

Android:

[image]

```
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl|Information|0|Client vs44176jaspe - An application message for topic xma/message-status was received
Mono.Debugging.VisualStudio.DebugLauncher|Error|0|Controller.Launch ()
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProgressReport|Error|0|System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x89710015): Unable to start debugging.

Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsDebugger4.LaunchDebugTargets4(UInt32 DebugTargetCount, VsDebugTargetInfo4[] pDebugTargets, VsDebugTargetProcessInfo[] pLaunchResults)
   at Mono.Debugging.VisualStudio.DebugLauncher.StartDebugger(SoftDebuggerSession session, StartInfo startInfo) in E:\A\_work\84\s\src\Debugging.VisualStudio\DebugLauncher.cs:line 49
   at Mono.Debugging.VisualStudio.MonoDebuggerLauncher.StartSession(StartInfo startInfo, SoftDebuggerSession session) in E:\A\_work\84\s\src\Debugging.VisualStudio\MonoDebuggerLauncher.cs:line 29
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.DebugCommandHandler.StartDebugger(IProgressReport progress, IAndroidProjectProperties properties, AndroidDevice device, String package, String activity, Project project) in E:\A\_work\30\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\DebugCommandHandler.cs:line 126
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.DebugCommandHandler.Execute(DebugCommand command, IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in E:\A\_work\30\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\DebugCommandHandler.cs:line 85
```

Comment: I have had problems with the debug when there are pending updates in the sdk manager in the case of Android

Comment: I updated the pending updates in the sdk manager but still no succes

Comment: Could you please open `tools->options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->MSBuild project build output verbosity/MSBuild project build log file verbosity-> select detailed or diagnostic` and paste the error part log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After pulling out hair for some time this is the fix:

Some how Mono Debugging for Visual Studio was diabled ...
Tools > Extensions and Updates> Mono Debugging for Visual Studio
enable and restart VS solved it

Comment: After lot of searching, this one worked for me. You just saved my day,  Thanks a lot!!!