# How do I install "Mono Debugging for Visual Studio"?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, mono

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410865/cant-deploy-on-devices-with-debugging-xamarin-android-and-ios), the reason I can't debug in Xamarin is that I don't have the "Mono Debugging for Visual Studio" extension enabled.  Not only do I not have enabled... I apparently don't have it installed!

Everywhere I've looked, everyone seems to imply it should be installed with Xamarin. However, in my case it was not.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Xamarin, with no luck.  I also checked the "Visual Studio Marketplace", but it's not there *(I tried the similar sounding "MonoRemoteDebugger", but that didn't help)*

So where do I get this extension?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solved it ?

Comment: I am also getting error for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to install Mono Debugging as an extensions after Visual Studio 15.8 preview.
The Visual Studio team has changed the Mono Debugger component to be a system component, which means it will not be visible and available anymore in the Extensions Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I found an extension Mono Tools

It says mono debugging is packaged into it. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GordianDotNet.VSMonoDebugger0d62).

> Enables Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 to deploy and debug a .Net application on a remote Linux machine with mono or dotnet core installed over SSH. Local debugging on Windows with installed mono is also supported.